# Photo is saved to datasnap only in .jpg but not in .png

Tags: delphi

I am sending a photo to the server using Datasnap by encoding it to base64 with the code below:

**My Application Code**

Converts the image to base64 and send to the server in Json format.

```
Memoria := TMemoryStream.Create;
Imagem.Picture.Bitmap.SaveToStream(Memoria);
Memoria.Position := 0;
StrEnv := TStringStream.Create;
TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(Memoria, StrEnv);
StrEnv.Position := 0;
JOImagem := TJSONObject.Create;
JOImagem.AddPair('photo', StrEnv.DataString);
```

**Datasnap Server**

Get the base64 image and save it as a jpg image.

```
lInStream := TStringStream.Create(JsonObj.GetValue('photo').Value);
lInStream.Position := 0;
lOutStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
TNetEncoding.Base64.Decode(lInStream, lOutStream);
lOutStream.Position := 0;
lOutStream.SaveToFile('photo-name' + '.jpg');
```

**Case 1.**

The image is saved successfully if I take the picture directly from my webcam.

**Case 2.**

If I take a .png or .jpg photo from the computer (using OpenPictureDialog) and save it. It is saved but when I open it says:

We don't support this file format.

**Problem**

It just works if I take the picture using the webcam, it doesn't work if I get it from the computer.

Comment: Did you add Vcl.Imaging.pngimage somewhere in your uses clause? Otherwise you will not have PNG support in your project.

Comment: It works fine by using Graphic instead of Bitmap, thank you @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the `TImage.Picture.Bitmap` property forces the picture to hold a BMP image (wiping out any current non-BMP image). This is [documented behavior](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TPicture.Bitmap):

> Use `Bitmap` to reference the picture object when it contains a bitmap. If `Bitmap` is referenced when the picture contains a Metafile or Icon graphic, the graphic won't be converted ([Types of Graphic Objects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Types_of_Graphic_Objects)). Instead, the original contents of the picture are discarded and `Bitmap` returns a new, blank bitmap.

As such, calling `Bitmap.SaveToStream()` will NEVER save to any format other than BMP.

If you load any format other than a BMP into the `Picture`, and want to preserve that format when accessing and saving the image, you need to use the `Picture.Graphic` property instead of the `Picture.Bitmap` property, eg:

```
Imagem.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(Memoria);
```